# Run Jquery function on each field

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to capitalize each of select option values which comes from Sql. 
Now, the following code works fine - but only on the first field...

```
function capitalize(str){
var text = str.text().replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1){ return $1.toUpperCase( ); });
return str.text(text);
}capitalize($('#op'));
```

My Html fields are looks something like this(i'm working with PUG/JADE and this is my best for trying to convert for demonstration purposes) :

```
<select class="select_input">
<option value=$emp['id'] id="op" selected="selected">$emp['value']</option>*
<?php foreach ($type as $type_val) ?>
<option value=$type_val['id']>$type_val['val']</option>
<?php endforeach?>

<select class="select_input">
<option value=$emp['id'] id="op" selected="selected">$emp['value']</option>*
<?php foreach ($type as $type_val) ?>
<option value=$type_val['id']>$type_val['val']</option>
<?php endforeach?>
```

- The first value that comes from DB.

As i mentioned before, the script runs only on the first field...

Comment: why dont you capitalize on server side?

Comment: ID should be unique. Use `$('.select_input option').text(function(i, t) { return t.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1){ return $1.toUpperCase( ); }});`

Answer (score 1):

You use `id` in the wrong way. Each id must be unique for html page.

```
// will work only for first object
capitalize($('#op'))
```

Try to use classes instead

```
<select class="select_input">
<option value=$emp['id'] id="op" class="option" selected="selected">$emp['value'] </option>*
<?php foreach ($type as $type_val) ?>
<option value=$type_val['id'] class="option">$type_val['val']</option>
<?php endforeach?>


capitalize($(".option"))
```

Comment: aleksv - This was my first option ... but it's kind of complicated be cause i'm using a specific project's methods which can't be altered....Sensei James - Thanks - unfortunately it creates another problem... now i get the whole array in each field.. instead of it's one value.....

Answer (score 0):

You *can* just use CSS to capitalize each dropdown item:

```
#op > option {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.... no other way then server side unfortunately

```
public function capitalize($arr)
  {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        $data[$key] = ucfirst($val);
    }

        return $data;
    }//end capitalize()
```